# My first lyx file only compiles like in verbatim mode. Why?

Tags: latex, lyx

I type the following text in Lyx, compile it with Apple+R, but get a verbatim version. How can I compile such a document as we do in pdflatex?

```
 \documentclass{article}

    \title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}

    \author{Jane Doe}

    \date{September 1994}

    \begin{document}

       \maketitle

       Hello world!

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post the .lyx file (it is just a text file so you can copy paste as with the .tex file) and also the .pdf you get when compiling it. Also, please say which version of LyX you use and exactly how you export (there are a few ways).

Comment: I copied the text abolve to my hello.lyx. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes. LyX has it's own format. So you have to "import it" into LyX. To do that, paste the above in hello.tex and then open LyX and go to File > Import > LaTeX (plain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX has it's own format. So you have to import the file into LyX. To do that, paste your code into hello.tex and then open LyX and go to File > Import > LaTeX (plain).